# How to change the default URL of thunderclient

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

Whenever we make a New Request, the default URL in the URL box is

`"https://www.thunderclient.com/welcome"`

How can we change this with our own URL?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a base url. It's super easy in Thunder Client-vs-code.
**Firstly,** got to `Collections`
You should have Folder for your project API. And click on `...` icon and got to `Settings` will move to **Collection Settings**
**Secondly,** Change the **Base Url** and **save** it.
You have done.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already requested in their Github issues but has still not been added yet.
So, the workaround I find is this:

- Go to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\rangav.vscode-thunder-client-1.18.7\dist` for Windows.
- Or go to `$HOME/.vscode/extensions/rangav.vscode-thunder-client-1.18.7/dist` for Mac or Linux.
- Open `extension.js` file with Notepad or any text editor.
- Find and replace this `https://www.thunderclient.com/welcome` with your desired URL.
- Save the file and restart VS Code.